# "Categories" for six authors

Tags: categories, tags

I'm setting up a blog for 6 siblings that are cooking all 125 recipes in a cookbook. "American Cake" if you're interested.

They'd like a mechanism for seeing all posts related to a recipe. Categories seem like a semi-natural choice, except that there are 125 of them. My client says everyone will just title their posts with the recipe name. I'm doubtful that six people can get the title right. Plus I'd have to find some way to show posts based on title. I'm sure that's possible and within my capabilities. But I'm hoping you can think of a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use tags? Every post carrying a recipe name can be listed in tags.